# What does * next to a file in Midnight Commander mean?

Tags: midnight-commander

Some files have a * next to them and others don't - why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should only show in the "User" display format. If you mean the `type` field, per `man mc`

> An **asterisk for executable files**, a slash for directories,
>          an at-sign for links, an equal sign for sockets, a  hyphen
>          for  character  devices,  a plus sign for block devices, a
>          pipe for fifos, a tilde for symbolic links to  directories
>          and  an  exlamation  mark for stalled symlinks (links that
>          point nowhere).

Otherwise, if you mean the `mark` field:

> An asterisk if the file is tagged, a space  if  it's not.